# ViewBag is not sending any value to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

In ASP.NET Core MVC, I'm facing trouble creating a login panel, I'm using sessions after the user is logged into the account and I'm storing the session values inside the ViewBag. But the ViewBag does not get any value inside of it, it rather gets null value inside it.

Here's the controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(userModel model)
        {
            var findValue = _context.users.Any(o => o.username == model.username);
            var findValue2 = _context.users.Any(o => o.password == model.password);
            if (findValue && findValue2)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Username", model.username);
            }
            return View(model);
        }

public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Username = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Username");
            return View();
        }
```

And here's the view
Index.cshtml

```
@model ComplaintManagement.Models.userModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Portal";
}

<h1>Welcome @ViewBag.Username</h1>
```

Login.cshtml

```
@model ComplaintManagement.Models.userModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 border login" style="background-color: #d3d1d1;">
        <h4 class="mt-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-user text-secondary"></i><br />
            Login
        </h4>
        <hr />
        <form method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Portal">
            <div class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="text-warning">@ViewBag.Name</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="mt-4 asp-for=" username"">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" asp-for="username" />
                <span></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="mt-4" asp-for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" required="required" asp-for="password" />
                <span></span>
            </div>

            <center>Don't have an account? <a asp-controller="Portal" asp-action="Register">Register here</a>.</center>
            <center><button value="login" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 w-25 mb-3 align-content-center">Login</button></center>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `var findValue = _context.users.Any(o => o.username == model.username);
            var findValue2 = _context.users.Any(o => o.password == model.password);` looks like it would not work correctly. The first query will find any user with the given username. The second one will find any user with the given password. There's no guarantee that both queries will find the **same** user. You need to re-think the logic. (Also, storing passwords in plain-text is a big security error too).

Comment: But...why are you even trying to build your own login system anyway? ASP.NET comes with its Identity feature which will add ready-made, secure login functionality to your application instantly. It has already solved all the bugs and security issues (such as the one I've mentioned) which can occur when trying to build a login system, including many more you probably haven't even thought of yet, and has features it would take you a long time to create. It's also customisable if you need to. There's really almost no reason not to use it.

Comment: See here for an introduction and tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Can you share your Startup.cs file? Or you can refer this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-state. Because I have a hunch that you not configure to use Session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Session and state management in ASP.NET Core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Here is a demo How to use Session in ASP.NET Core.

**1. Codes of Startup Configurations**

`AddSession` in ConfigureServices, `UseSession` in Configure.

```
 public class Startup
 {

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
        ...
        services.AddSession();
        ...
     }
     
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        ....
    }
```

**2. Codes of Controller**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(userModel model)
    {    
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.username
            ) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.password))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

       //var user = await _context.users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.username == model.username && x.password == model.password);

        //if (user != null)
        if (model.username.Equals("test") && model.password.Equals("123"))
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", model.username);
        }
        else
            ViewBag.error = "Invalid Account";
         
        return View("Index");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.Remove("username");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**3. Codes of View**

```
   <h3>Login Page</h3>
    @ViewBag.error
    <form method="post" asp-controller="account" asp-action="login">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

**4. Codes of returning View when success**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

<h3>Success Page</h3>
Welcome @Context.Session.GetString("username")
<br>
<a asp-controller="account" asp-action="logout">Logout</a>
```

### Test result

[image]

Comment: @FahadAzeem, Your codes of `Viewbag`  is right and I updated the code about how to use session for login operation. You could try.